# Restrict Navigation with server response

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to restrict the Navigation by the response of the server. Here I used

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);
```

This code to get response. 
Can anyone solve it for restrict Navigation for another view controller.

Comment: what's wrong with the condition statements . if(statusCode == )

Comment: nothing wrong i just got it but not with the if(statusCode==). it done  by if ([response statusCode]==200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It done by the below code.

```
if ([response statusCode]==200)
```

{

homeViewController *tempVC =[[homeViewController alloc]
          initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
    } .